# Is the web.config/app.config element configSections deprecated in DotNet4.5?

Tags: asp.net, paypal, web-config

I have an old application in ASP.Net (3.5) that needs upgrading, however, after updating to 4.5, a configSections element in the web.config file is not recognized and the app fails to load. Did something change here?

the following used to work...

```
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="paypal" type="PayPal.SDKConfigHandler, PayPal" />
  </configSections>

  <!-- PayPal SDK settings -->
  <paypal>
    <settings>
      <add name="mode" value="sandbox"/>
      <add name="clientId" value="YOUR APPLICATION CLIENT ID"/>
      <add name="clientSecret" value="YOUR APPLICATION CLIENT SECRET"/>
    </settings>
  </paypal>
</configuration>
```

but no joy

```
HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error
The requested page cannot be accessed because the related configuration data for the page is invalid.


Config Source:
   22:   
   23:   <configSections>
   24:     <section name="paypal" type="PayPal.SDKConfigHandler, PayPal" />
```

Comment: I have a website in 4.6.1 with a `configSections` element.

Comment: Ensure your application pool user has read permissions on the website directory. Also go to IIS Manager, select your website in left pane and then double click Handlers icon in the right pane. If the http handlers list loads it means web.config is valid

Comment: In recent versions you should use config section like this: `<section name="paypal" type="PayPal.Manager.SDKConfigHandler, PayPalCoreSDK" />`. I recommend you to include complete error message with error code (e.g. `0x{hex number}`) because the problem will be easier to read and analyze.

Comment: okay - I'm running from VisualStudio 2017 w/ IISExpress.  I think this is actually a VS2017 configuration issue. I'm going to run it on IIS instead.

Comment: Tetsuya - when you say "recent versions" what do you mean? Versions of what? DotNet?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. It had nothing to do with permissions, IISExpress, or anything else, but only the position in the  section. I moved  element to just under the  element and there's no error anymore. Go figure.

```
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="paypal" type="PayPal.SDKConfigHandler, PayPal" />
  </configSections>
...
```

I've written my own XML parsers in the past that read the entire file and are not dependent on the order of the elements (just so long as it follows the structure & required elements are present). I incorrectly assumed that order does not matter in the web.config file. Good to know (probably save lots of coders headaches in the future).